# Is anyone able to tell me in English what the read seal says on this painting, please! (Characters identified: 史達畫印)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

[image]

Hoping someone can tell me in English what this red seal/ chop on a Chinese painting is saying. Is it it the artists name and what does it translate to. Thank you!

Comment: Photo provided is very blurry. Please edit it to another one, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the characters are "史達畫印". I believe this seal belongs to "薛史達" (XUE, Shida). "史達" is the first name of this artist. The other 2 characters "畫印" mean "painting seal". So the meaning of the seal is: 史達's seal for paintings.